# PHP codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter-3

My view:

```
<div class="row eva-add-mainbox">
            <div class="col s3 eva-aditem-leftbox">
                <p>Product Item Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col s9">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input type="text" name="pname" class="validate" id="proName">
                    <label for="icon_prefix">Product Item Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my controller:-

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('itemCode', 'Item Code', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pDescription', 'Product Description', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productPrice', 'Price', 'required|max_length[12]|regex_match[/^[0-9.]+$/]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('proQuantity', 'Quantity', 'max_length[12]|numeric|greater_than[0]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
            $test = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $extension = end($test);
            $name = rand(100, 999) . '.' . $extension;
            $location = './images/' . $name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location);
            $b = $this->session->userdata('business');
            $pdata['product_code'] = $this->input->post('itemCode');
            $pdata['title'] = $this->input->post('pName');
            $pdata['discription'] = $this->input->post('description');
            $pdata['business_id'] = $b->biz_id;
            $pdata['price'] = $this->input->post('price');
            $proQuantity = $this->input->post('proQuantity');
            $pdata['image'] = $location;
            $pAttribute = $this->input->post('pAttribute');
            $pValue = $this->input->post('pValue');
        }

        $result = $this->product_model->setProductData($pdata, $pAttribute, $pValue, $proQuantity);
    }else
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
```

I get an error as:

> The Product Description field is required.
>
> The Price field is required.
>
> The Name field is required.

Can any one explain why it is happen?

Comment: because you set rules that require those fields?? `$this->form_validation->set_rules('itemCode', 'Item Code', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pDescription', 'Product Description', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');` etc... . Just because those fields aren't in your HTML form doesn't mean the controller isn't expecting them to be submitted. If you want a cut-down version of the form where only some of the fields are going to be input, you'll need a separate ViewModel with its own validation rules.

Comment: Because you've set them to required in your validation rules

Answer (score 1):

In validation you validate these three fields thats why its coming

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pDescription', 'Product Description', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('proQuantity', 'Quantity', 'max_length[12]|numeric|greater_than[0]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[38]|xss_clean');
```